# Get chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get chrome storage.
but outside of **chrome.storage.local.get** function It's not working.

My code is below

```
chrome.storage.local.get('Setting', function(data){
    var Setting = data.Setting;
});
console.log(Setting);
```

Comment: Chrome API callbacks are asynchronous. See the link for solutions. In short, the value should be used inside the callback or passed via Promise (also async/await).